# analytics-stream-maven-plugin can not be found in http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/maven/

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-integration-studio

I am using the developer studio 3.8 on Eclipse 4.4 (lunar) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I created a new analytics project using the "Analytics Project" under the "WSO2" categories. see picture

[image]

when I built the project using the mvn command line "mvn clean install"

I got the following error

```
wjz@jz:~/wso2/gubnoicep$ mvn clean install 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/maven/analytics-stream-maven-plugin/1.0.0/analytics-stream-maven-plugin-1.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.wso2.maven:analytics-stream-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/maven/analytics-stream-maven-plugin/1.0.0/analytics-stream-maven-plugin-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.gubnoi:gubnoicep:1.0.0 (/home/wjz/wso2/gubnoicep/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.wso2.maven:analytics-stream-maven-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.wso2.maven:analytics-stream-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
wjz@jz:~/wso2/gubnoicep$
```

I checked the POM.xml and find the following reference

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>analytics-stream-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>stream</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>pom-gen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactLocation>.</artifactLocation>
              <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
```

I traced into the indicated links: 
http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/maven/

and can not find the expected plugin: analytics-stream-maven-plugin

please advise

thanks

Comment: This seems a bug in the Dev Studio. Could you please create an JIRA?

Comment: Seems that CEP plugin is not published to nexus yet

Answer (score 1):

CEP plugins were implemented after Developer Studio 3.8.0 maven plugin release. Hence plugins are not yet hosted. Team plans to release maven plugins by next week. Then you can use maven build. Till maven plugins are released you can build the project using developer studio itself which will generate your CAR file to be deployed in WSO2 CEP.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives